# Why service worker fails to load pages in offline mode with angular routes?

Tags: angular, angular7, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

### Problem

I created a new angular project and made it a progressive web app by running  `ng add @angular/pwa`. Now everything works as it is supposed to but when I change the route from `someurl.com/` to `someurl.com/some/route` then the service worker cannot load the page in offline mode.

If I build and serve the application locally using http-server, then everything works just fine when I load the page `localhost:8080/` but when I navigate to `localhost:8080/some/route`, then http-server returns 404 to the browser.

I want to figure out how to get the service worker function properly with different routes (i.e. `/some/route`), and load the page offline as a PWA should.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Run `ng n <project-name>`
2. Type 'y' when prompts to enable routing in the project
3. Run `ng add @angular/pwa --project <project-name>`
4. Create a component (let's say it's call LoginComponent)
5. Add a route for that component in the app-routing.module.ts:

```js
{
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
}
```

6. Run `ng build --prod`
7. Run `cd dist/<project-name>/`
8. Run `http-server`
9. On chrome, navigate to localhost:8080/login
10. Go offline, and refresh the page

Comment: I follow your steps but it works on both offline and online

Comment: any other instruction to reproduce?

Comment: I believe what happened was that you defined a path to redirect "/" to the "/<component>" and http-server successfully servers index.html for "/", then it gets cached by the service worker, then you get redirected to "/<component>", and since the index.html is already cached you're seeing the page load perfectly fine.

Comment: To reproduce the problem exactly, after you get redirected to "/component", on dev tools, go to application tab, and clear all service worker cached data and refresh the page.

Comment: still working for me... did your build was successful? could you please give screenshot of what error did you get doing this.

Comment: Try enabling `useHash` property to true in your `app-routing.module.ts`. `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]`

Comment: @Chaitanya this method works since basically there's no routing and the index.html will be served and cached by the service worker. However, I need actual routing instead of using hash, and it wouldn't be ideal to make such change in an existing application